# Como llamar funcion dentro de otra funcion con un parametro JS

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tengo dos funciones javascript, una en donde agrego unas celdas a una tabla, y la otra que ocupo para eliminar una fila entera de esta tabla, lo que estoy tratando es llamar esta función de eliminar dentro de la otra función.

Script para eliminar la fila completa

```
function Remove(button) {
        //Determine the reference of the Row using the Button.
        var row = $(button).closest("TR");
        var name = $("TD", row).eq(0).html();

        //Delete the Table row using it's Index.
        table.deleteRow(row[0].rowIndex);

    };
```

Script en el que estoy tratando de llamar la función de eliminar

```
function Seleccionar() {
    var id = $("#selectlist").val()
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Pedido/GetProduct?Id=" + id,
        success: function (data) {
            var tBody = $("#example1 > TBODY")[0];
            var row = tBody.insertRow(-1);

            //Cantidad Input
            var cantidad = document.createElement('input')
            cantidad.type = 'number'
            cantidad.style.width = '170px'
            cantidad.style.height = '30px'
            cantidad.value= '1'
            cantidad.style.textAlign = "center"
            cantidad.className = 'form-control'

            //Opcion Eliminar
            var eliminar = document.createElement("img")
            eliminar.src = "../dist/img/eliminar.png"
            eliminar.style.width = '25px'
            eliminar.style.height = '25px'
            eliminar.onclick = function(){
                Remove();
                };

            //Add ID cell.
            var cell = $(row.insertCell(0));
            cell.html(data.id);
            //Add Nombre cell.
            cell = $(row.insertCell(1));
            cell.html(data.nombre);
            //Add Precio cell.
            cell = $(row.insertCell(2));
            cell.html(data.precio)
            //Add Cantidad cell
            cell = $(row.insertCell(3));
            cell.html(cantidad)

            //Add Eliminar cell
            cell = $(row.insertCell(4));
            cell.html(eliminar)


        }
    });
};
```

En esta parte es donde intento llamar la función para así poder agregarlo a una celda de la tabla

```
//Opcion Eliminar
var eliminar = document.createElement("img")
eliminar.src = "../dist/img/eliminar.png"
eliminar.style.width = '25px'
eliminar.style.height = '25px'
eliminar.onclick = function(){
     Remove();
   };
```

Adicional como podría hacer para cambiar la anchura de la celda que estoy ingresando a la tabla, y centrar su contenido.

```
//Add ID cell.
var cell = $(row.insertCell(0));
cell.html(data.id);
//Add Nombre cell.
cell = $(row.insertCell(1));
cell.html(data.nombre);
//Add Precio cell.
cell = $(row.insertCell(2));
cell.html(data.precio)
//Add Cantidad cell
cell = $(row.insertCell(3));
cell.html(cantidad)               
//Add Eliminar cell
cell = $(row.insertCell(4));
cell.html(eliminar)
```

Comment: Podrías mostrar un registro , para ver el JSON y hacer una prueba para mostrar-te, no es necesario datos reales, entiendo que es estructura, {id: 0, nombre: '', precio: 2.12 } ?

Comment: @JoelGarciaNuño Aca muestro mi tabla con los datos ingresados https://imgur.com/a/Xxv5AWA en el boton X es en donde deseo llamar la funcion de eliminar

Comment: A mí me dice, que table no está definido

Comment: @JoelGarciaNuño Mmm la verdad la tabla la lleno con datos que selecciono en un dropdownlist, pero aca yo solamente deseo saber como llamar esa funcion

Comment: Mira a ver sí te ayuda lo que te puse, realmente al asignar el "onclick" es tener en cuenta de que el elemento está en la vista, html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// JS Vanilla.
function Remove(button) { button.parentElement.parentElement.remove(); };
//Opcion Eliminar (( ABSTRAIDO A UNA FUNCION PARA TENER UNA INSTANCIA UNICA ))
function crearBotonEliminar () {
  const eliminar = document.createElement("img");
  eliminar.src = "../dist/img/eliminar.png";
eliminar.style.width = '25px';
eliminar.style.height = '25px';
return eliminar;
}
   
    // AL TOCAR LA IMAGEN SE LLAMA SELECCIONAR
    function Seleccionar() {
    var id = $("#selectlist").val();
    // SIMULACION DE DATA RECIBIDA EN EL SUCCESS:
    const data = {
          id: 10,
          precio: 2.12,
          nombre: 'Pelota de Baloncesto'
      };
        
            var tBody = $("#example1 > TBODY")[0];
            var row = tBody.insertRow(-1);
            
             //Cantidad Input
            var cantidad = document.createElement('input')
            cantidad.type = 'number'
            cantidad.style.width = '170px'
            cantidad.style.height = '30px'
            cantidad.value= '1'
            cantidad.style.textAlign = "center"
            cantidad.className = 'form-control'
/*

Funcion a parte..

            //Opcion Eliminar
            var eliminar = document.createElement("img")
            eliminar.src = "../dist/img/eliminar.png"
            eliminar.style.width = '25px'
            eliminar.style.height = '25px'
            eliminar.onclick = function(){
                Remove();
                };
*/
            //Add ID cell.
            var cell = $(row.insertCell(0));
            cell.html(data.id);
            //Add Nombre cell.
            cell = $(row.insertCell(1));
            cell.html(data.nombre);
            //Add Precio cell.
            cell = $(row.insertCell(2));
            cell.html(data.precio);
            //Add Cantidad cell
            cell = $(row.insertCell(3));
            cell.html(cantidad);
            //Add Eliminar cell
            cell = $(row.insertCell(4));
            //Obtener eliminar
            eliminar = crearBotonEliminar();
            cell.html(eliminar);
            
            //Despues de mostrar-lo en el HTML
            eliminar.onclick = function(){
              Remove(this);
            };
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="example1">
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th>
      <!-- Iria en tú #seleccionar x item -->
      <button onclick="Seleccionar()"></button>
    </th>
   </tr>  
</thead>
<tbody>

<!-- Cargado desde Javascript -->

</tbody>
</table>
```

***Cambios, como hacer la celda del botón más ancha y centrar el elemento.***

Para la imagen,

***Quitar estás dos líneas :***

```
eliminar.style.width = '25px';
eliminar.style.height = '25px';
```

***Añadir hoja de estilos, css :***

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  width: 30px;
}
```

*también puedes remplazar-lo por JavaScript:*

```
eliminar.style.minWidth = "100%";
eliminar.style.width = "30px";
eliminar.style.height = "auto";
```

Para la tabla :

***Añadir un 100% de width,***

```
<table id="example1" width="100%">
```

***En el success, sobre la celda, la última :***

```
$(cell).css({"width":"40%","text-align":"center"});
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! definitivamente me ha funcionado. Solo por ultimo como podria hacer para cambiarle el tamaño a dicha celda y agregar al centro el boton? Gracias

Comment: Te he puesto unos indicativos, suerte ^^, está sería una manera de añadir el width a la celda

Comment: Muchas gracias!